# bash how to extract iface inet and mask from ifconfig

Tags: bash

Can anyone help filter the information from     `ipconfig`
the information im getting is

```
enp37s0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 2c:41:38:15:41:30  
          inet addr:192.168.0.105  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::89be:e3f9:b746:19ed/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4593332 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2313662 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:6506620971 (6.5 GB)  TX bytes:182579364 (182.5 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:9574 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9574 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1100854 (1.1 MB)  TX bytes:1100854 (1.1 MB)

wlo1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d0:df:9a:6c:7c:1d  
          inet addr:192.168.0.103  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::225d:a288:5fa7:2237/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:124147 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2681 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:32988267 (32.9 MB)  TX bytes:266523 (266.5 KB)
```

And i would like to get.

1. enp37s0 : 192.168.0.105/255.255.255.0
2. lo : 127.0.0.1/255.0.0.0
3. wlo1: 192.168.0.103/255.255.255.0

Comment: Read `sed` man pages and also please, read [how to ask useful questions aka MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax will change depending on what operating system you're using, but you can use some `sed` commands to get the output you want. For example the command on my Arch Linux system is `ifconfig` (`f` not `p`) and my output is formatted a little differently. But here's something that ought to work on your system:

```
ipconfig | tr '\n' '~' | sed 's/~~/\n/g' | sed 's/~/ /g' | sed -E 's/^\s*(\S+)\s+.*\s+inet\s+(\S+)\s.*$/\1 \2/g'
```

We do a few things here:

1. Replace all the newlines with some unused character, here `~`, because your interface name (enp37s0) and IP address (192.168.0.105) are on different lines, and we need to merge them onto the same line
2. Replace `~~` (which would have been two consecutive newlines - the separator between interfaces) with a single newline. This will effectively make `sed` operate on each interface separately in the remaining steps
3. Replace `~` (which would have been a single newline) with a space; this ensures we don't inadvertently join any parts of the original output (for example, we might get `30inet` from the first two lines being joined together, but we want `30 inet` since we're looking for `inet`
4. Finally the main part, we extract the first word on each line, then we look for the `inet` word and also extract the word immediately after it on that same line. We also discard everything after the first word and before `inet`, and everything after the word after `inet`. Here a "word" means anything separated by whitespace. `\s` in a regex matches whitespace and `\S` matches anything that isn't whitespace, so `^\s*(\S+)\s+` finds our first word, `.*` gets rid of anything following it, `\s+inet\s+(\S+)\s` finds `inet` and the word after it, and `.*$` gets rid of anything to the end of the line.

This will produce the following in your case:

```
enp37s0 addr:192.168.0.105
lo addr:127.0.0.1
wlo1 addr:192.168.0.103
```

If you want to see what each individual step does, you can of course just execute part of the command.

Removing the `addr:` and/or adding the `Mask` into the result is left as an exercise to the reader as similar techniques can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Challenge accepted :-)

Try this one-liner:

```
for ip in $(hostname -I | grep -Eo '([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*'); do echo ""$(ifconfig | grep -B1 "inet addr:"$ip | cut -d " " -f1 | tr -d " ")" : "$ip"/"$(ifconfig | grep "inet addr:"$ip | grep -Eo 'Mask:?([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -Eo '([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*') ; done;
```

Produces something like this on my Debian:

```
wlan1 : 192.168.1.116/255.255.255.0
docker_gwbridge : 172.18.0.1/255.255.0.0
br-2c830dcde04d : 172.25.0.1/255.255.0.0
br-d6bc6df716ef : 172.21.0.1/255.255.0.0
br-d6fccd14dfad : 172.19.0.1/255.255.0.0
br-df4c2b24c7c0 : 172.24.0.1/255.255.0.0
docker0 : 172.17.0.1/255.255.0.0
br-ef0e82befd79 : 172.22.0.1/255.255.0.0
br-fad2fced45f8 : 172.20.0.1/255.255.0.0
```

Some details if you're interested:

```
for ip in $(hostname -I | grep -Eo '([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*'); do
```

loop over IPv4 addresses in `hostname` output

```
ifconfig | grep -B1 "inet addr:"$ip | cut -d " " -f1 | tr -d " ")
```

take a matching line and the one above in `ifconfig`, then take the first word of that line above the IP address ... which should be the name of the interface

```
ifconfig | grep "inet addr:"$ip | grep -Eo 'Mask:?([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -Eo '([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*')
```

take that matching line again and search for a token with "Mask:", then extract the mask

Ok, I know, it is not pure bash, might not work on all OS variants, not even pure sed/grep on ifconfig, but... was fun to code it!